# Does wrapping turkey while resting make the skin soggy

Tags: roasting, turkey

I normally rest turkey (in 16 - 24 lb range) for 45 - 60 minutes, loosely tented in foil only.   I'm looking at a number of suggestions for longer resting time*, but they usually refer to tenting the turkey in foil and then wrapping in towels.  This would seem to keep in a lot of steam, not just heat.  Does the skin stay crisp?

- I'm not thinking of a "full Gordon" at 3 hours but perhaps going to 90 - 120 minutes; I see a lot of comments that 2 hours works very well.

Comment: IMO wrapping the turkey in towels will remove any crispy bits and pieces of skin of the turkey.

Comment: That would be my fear.   This weekend I did do a 90 minute rest, with the bird just tented in foil.  We had very crisp skin and it was still warm. So based on one data point no need for towels!!!   But no proof of the effect of towels either!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the skin would get less crisp, as towels would trap steam inside.

Also, skin (as with bacon) crisps as it cools, so if you keep the turkey warmer then the skin will crisp up less than if you let it rest to a lower temperature